# How to convert a json file to parser by argparse?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, argparse

I have a json file like,

```
{
    "model_name_or_path": "microsoft/layoutlmv3-base",
    "config_name": null,
    "tokenizer_name": null,
    "cache_dir": null,
    "model_revision": "main",
    "use_auth_token": false
}
```

I want to convert this JSON file into a parser format, so as to use by this method:

```
print(model_args.model_name_or_path)
print(model_args.tokenizer_name) #etc..
```

I followed some instruction by using `argparse` in python, but still have no idea after creating a new argparser.

```
with open("model_args.json", 'r') as f:
    model_json = json.load(f)

    model_args = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # model_args.add_argument(default=model_json)
    # model_args.parse_args(namespace=argparse.Namespace(**json.loads(f)))
    print(model_args.model_name_or_path)
```

What should I do next step, if I want to add this json file into parser?

Comment: method `parse_args` returns Namespace object full of your parameters. `args = model_args.parse_args(namespace=argparse.Namespace(**json.loads(f)))`

Comment: @ukBaz thanks, but I am not sure if they are different as parser when training model. Let me use your answer firstly

Comment: @ukBaz I face a problem, that shows `'types.SimpleNamespace' object has no attribute 'get_process_log_level'` actually, my json file from 'transformers import TrainingArguments'  and it is not convenient if I input args in cmd every time, so I save these parameters to json file firstly. I notice that 'TrainingArguments()' have convert to namespace()

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do.  `argparse.Namespace(**json.loads(f))` makes a Namespace object which can be used as though those values were entered via commandline and proper parser.  And supply that namespace to the `parse_args` of a different parser, would add those values to that parser's output. (with some possible overwrites).  Otherwise I don't see what you can mean "covert the json into a parser".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like maybe you are looking for a `namedtuple`.

For example:

```
import json
from collections import namedtuple

json_text = """{
    "model_name_or_path": "microsoft/layoutlmv3-base",
    "config_name": null,
    "tokenizer_name": null,
    "cache_dir": null,
    "model_revision": "main",
    "use_auth_token": false
}"""

data = json.loads(json_text)

ModelArgs = namedtuple('ModelArgs', list(data.keys()))

model_args = ModelArgs(**data)

print(model_args.model_name_or_path)
print(model_args.tokenizer_name)
print(model_args.cache_dir)
```

OUTPUT:

```
microsoft/layoutlmv3-base
None
main
```

Documentation for `namedtuple` found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields)